# bootstrap popovers working in one place but not the other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

So this seems strange. In my Rails 4 app,  have two popovers, one in the menu, and one in a view's sidebar.

Each view has the header partial (asset pipeline) and the nav partial (with the first popover) loaded into it.

The popover in the nav works fine, but the popover in the view sidebar does not.

In console I can see the header, all the JS files for the pipeline, and I am not getting the `(...).popover is not a function` which would indicate to me that the jQuery is indeed being loaded.

In my Application.js file, I have

`$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('placement', 'bottom');`

Which as I understand, should initialize all the popovers at once. I have also tried including that line within the view itself within script tags.

The popover in questions is currently using the exact code provided by bootstrap while I try to get it working, and is wrapped in an if/else:

```
  <% if current_user.nil? %>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover title" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">Click to toggle popover</button>
    <% else %>
             <%= button_to "Contribute!", new_project_charge_path(:project_id => @project.id), method: :get, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

I have also tried removing the if/else to see if that was the problem, but it makes no difference. What do you think is the problem here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this... I think you are not setting the options correctly.

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({placement : 'bottom'});
```

Comment: Well I'll be darned! I have googled this to death. I would have never guessed, since it was working fine for the first popover...thank you so much!